# Is there a way to concatenate the query parameters in a GET API call?

Tags: api, rest, get, scim

I am trying to hit a GET API call using SCIM protocol with multiple filter query parameters like firstName, lastName.
I want to have another query parameter which can combine firstName and lastName.
E.g. ?filter=firstName co "Praful" or lastName co "Praful" **or firstName||lastName co "Praful M"**

Is there a way to get the highlighted filter work? So I want to search if my text is a combination of firstName and lastName.

Comment: can you use "or" with "co"? https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pingone/page/kti1564020489340.html

Comment: Isn't this a workaround for your requirement `filter=name.givenName co Praful or name.familyName co Praful or (name.givenName eq Praful and name.familyName sw M)` ?